# Want to extract the substring from string using regex in powershell scripting

Tags: powershell

I want to know the status of my running process from the detailed description using REGEX in Windows powershell scripting.
I want to extract RUNNING from this string

> Name: Process_name Started 2008-04-21 11:33 Status **RUNNING**
>   Checkpoint Lag  00:00:00

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, could you detail what you've tried and what your expected results are, you'll get better quality answers if you do.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to check whether `"Status RUNNING"` is part of the string? There appears to be no need to use a regex (unless you want to guard against the case that a process might contain these words in its name, which you would need to specify in your question).

Comment: Split the string according to space and loop through the result. [Here's an example on how to do it](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/parse-string-in-a-bash-script-280252/)

Comment: @ClydeFrog a simple regex can extract it easier and more fool proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract `RUNNING` or `STOPPED` etc. you can try the following:

```
PS > $s = "Name: Process_name Started 2008-04-21 11:33 Status RUNNING Checkpoint Lag 00:00:00", "Name: Process2_name Started 2008-04-21 11:33 Status STOPPED Checkpoint Lag 00:00:00"

PS > $s | % { if ($_ -match "Status (.+) Checkpoint") { 
    #Return match from group 1
    $Matches[1] 
    }
}

RUNNING
STOPPED
```

If you're reading a log-file, you can send the content of it directly to the test like this:

```
PS > Get-Content mylog.txt | % { if ($_ -match "Status (.+) Checkpoint") { 
    #Return match from group 1
    $Matches[1] 
    }
}
```

This is extracting everything between "Status " and " Checkpoint", as long as it's at least 1 character (can be mulitple words also).

Comment: I think This will do the job. Thanks Graimer

Comment: Hello Graimer, I got what i was lookin for. But there is something more which i would like to work upon. If in my $s variable is multiline with many instances of status like: "Name: Process_name Started 2008-04-21 11:33 Status RUNNING Checkpoint Lag 00:00:00   Name:Process_name2 Started 2008-04-21 11.34 Status Running Checkpoint Lag 00:00:00" ,how can i get the output as status for both process at same time. like it shud be RUNNING and then again RUNNING. I am very much new to powershell scripting. Please help me out with this. Thank You

Comment: Hey. See updated answer. It now takes an array(multiline) and sends one by one through the pipeline (`|`) into a foreach loop (`%`) that looks for status and extracts it in one line at a time.

Answer (score 3):

Using -replace

```
$text = 'Name: Process_name Started 2008-04-21 11:33 Status RUNNING Checkpoint Lag 00:00:00'
$text -replace '.+\sStatus\s(\S+)\sCheckpoint.+','$1'
RUNNING
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for Windows processes, doesn't it make more sense to use Get-Process which supports properties and filtering, or the WMI equivalent, gwmi Win32_Process?

Might be way off the mark here so correct me if I'm mistaken!

Comment: The process i am trying to catch is not a windows process. i mean to say that it doesn't create any service or process in task managaer. It just runs in background. So i am not able to catch the status of process using Get-Process.